# React update url using selectbox on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning react and I found a video on youtube of someone creating a PWA using a news api, I decided I would try replicate it using react as his video was just in vanilla JS and I learn things a little easier if I build stuff.

on the news API there is a sources and an articles API.

Articles:

`https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&apiKey=${API_KEY}`

Sources:

`https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en`

I have created a select box which contains the sources from the sources api and I get the news by updating the source in the URL from the select box. I have managed to get the select box to put its value into state onchange but I cant get that up to the `NewsItem` component to change the source in the articles url.

I have put a codepen together here https://codepen.io/crash1989/pen/JZLQxr it is slightly different to how I have my code, as I have had to create the sources and  news manually as I didnt want to publish my API key.

Where you see `componentDidMount` I am using `async/await` functions to get the data from the API and putting it into state.

In my actual code I want to have a url like this for the articles `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=${this.state.source}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`

so the bottom line is I need help getting the select box value into the `NewsItem` component to update my news.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly and it's hard to tell from the CodePen since it's different from your original code, but you probably want to update the state of the component when you get the results back from the request. If you're already doing this, you could try to post your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Your App is build like this

```
<App>
  <Nav />
  <News />
</App>
```

You select a value in `<Nav />` and want to pass it to `<News />`. You should do so by storing the value in the state of App, and pass the value and the changeHandler as property to the children.

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         source: "BBC News"
      }
   }

   setSource = source => {
      this.setState({source})
   }

   render() {
       let {source} = this.state
       return (
           <div>
               <Nav source={source} setSource={this.setSource} />
               <News source={source} />
           </div>
       )
   }
}
```